# Streamlit : Thread ‘ThreadPoolExecutor-8_0’: missing ScriptRunContext

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, streamlit, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use python concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() to run multiple instances of “ingestion” function for given metadata.
“final” is a list of tuples that holds the values of arguments for the function called.

As per the existing discussions, I installed streamlit==1.12.0 to use add_script_run_ctx()

Debug info
Streamlit version: 1.12.0
Python version: 3.9.13
PipEnv

Original python script without streamlit dependency (was working fine):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(lambda f: ingestion(*f), final)
```

Code snippet:

```
from streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner import add_script_run_ctx
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        abc = executor.map(lambda f: ingestion(*f), final)
        add_script_run_ctx(abc)
```

Expected behavior:

The code should enter the “ingestion” function and iterate through tuples present in the “final” list.

Actual behavior:

Thread ‘ThreadPoolExecutor-8_0’: missing ScriptRunContext
‘generator’ object has no attribute ‘streamlit_script_run_ctx’